# Storing and retrieving IplImages from vector?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to store `IplImage`'s ( grabbed from a video file) into a vector and then playback from this `iplimage` vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "highgui.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture=cvCreateFileCapture("D:\\Video\\Hands tracking.avi");
    vector<IplImage*> imagesNames[2];

    //playing video
    while(1)
   {
       IplImage* img=cvQueryFrame(capture);
       cvShowImage("Video Opencv example nd testing purpose",img);

       imagesNames[0].push_back(img);

       char c = cvWaitKey(30);
       if(c==27) break;
   }

  cvDestroyWindow( "Video Opencv example nd testing purpose" );
  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

// play back grabbed IplImages
  for(unsigned i=0; imagesNames[0].size();i++)
  {
    cvShowImage("PlayBack from IplImages vector",imagesNames[0][i]);

    char c = cvWaitKey(30);

    if(c==27) break;
   }
return 0;
}
```

But the playback part of the above program is not working and showing error at runtime.

Comment: carefully engineer the for loop's test condition :0

Comment: This is a guaranteed way to crush your PC by eating gigabytes of RAM. You should definitely avoid it if your videos are longer than a 2-3 seconds. A decompressed video is orders of magnitude bigger than the compressed AVI file

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "highgui.h"
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    CvCapture* capture=cvCreateFileCapture("D:\\Video\\Hands tracking.avi");
    vector<IplImage*> imagesNames;

    //playing video
    while(1)
   {
       IplImage* img=cvQueryFrame(capture);
       cvShowImage("Video Opencv example nd testing purpose",img);

       imagesNames.push_back(img);

      char c = cvWaitKey(30);
      if(c==27)
       break;

   }

  cvDestroyWindow( "Video Opencv example nd testing purpose" );
  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

// play back grabbed IplImages
 for(unsigned i=0; i < imagesNames.size();i++)
 {

    cvShowImage("PlayBack from IplImages vector",imagesNames[i]);

    char c = cvWaitKey(30);

    if(c==27)
    break;

}
return 0;


}
```

Comment: geez , doesn't that for loop is endless : `for(unsigned i=0; imagesNames.size();i++)` or am I missing lollipop

Comment: still not working.. i mean.. now just one image is grabbed from the  vector in d playbackpart!!

Comment: @inkooboo code is not working!! and program ends up with just one successful image retrieval from the vector!!... in the playback part of d program!!

Comment: @Lokesh Kumar I don know what problem is now. I just corrected you work with vector. Research yourself opencv docs.

Comment: @LokeshKumar  Your code is correct but place the cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
 at the end it will not crash, I tested it.